# Attempting to make firebase.auth().currentUser a promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex

When a user logs in, I'm trying to send them to a restricted page. So I'm protecting the route by checking for the user object. The problem is that when a user is created or logging in, the auth doesn't immediately change, so after creating or logging in, `firebase.auth().currentUser` can return `null` for a couple of milliseconds. So if I send them to the page, it will return an error.

This is what I'm trying to do in an attempt for the route to wait a while to see if the auth changes. I'm wondering if there is any issues with the code or a better way to write this.

P.S. I know that I can check for `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`, but I don't understand how I can use it upon user creation or log in. It just runs in the background and I can't just send users a route when auth changes with no context. It also doesn't have a timeout.

```
getUser( { commit } ) {
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject )=> {
    let user, i = 0
    function checkForUser() {
      setTimeout( ()=> {
        i++
        user = firebase.auth().currentUser
        if ( user ) {
          router.push( { path: '/restricted' } )
          resolve()
        } else if ( i > 30 ) {
          reject( { message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.' } )
        } else {
          checkForUser()
        }
      }, 100 )
   }  
   checkForUser()
  } )
},
```

Comment: Seems like you'd also want to show the code that signs in the user, since what you're showing here is dependent on that other code, and how you might be handling its results.

Comment: There's a nice long GitHub issue for this (that's taking far too long for them to fix IMO) that's got some good work-arounds listed ~ https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/462

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm actually using this in a couple of different places where I need the user object to be present. So I can run this function and wait for it to either pass or fail. But somehow it feels a little messy, wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @Phil I've seen the thread but the solution doesn't seem to handle a timeout and just gets stuck if the user object doesn't get populated.

Answer (score 6):

This is a long answer because Firebase has yet to come to the table and do anything about https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/462

---

Here's how I've done it in the past, synchronising the user in Vuex.

For this, I've got two mutations and a handy getter but there's nothing too special there

```js
state: {
  user: null
},
getters: {
  isAuthenticated: state => typeof state.user === 'object' && state.user !== null
},
mutations: {
  LOGIN: (state, user) => (state.user = user),
  LOGOUT: state => (state.user = null)
}
```

I have a `firebase/index.js` file for configuring the Firebase App that looks like this

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
// import any other Firebase libs like firestore, etc
import config from './config'
import store from '../store' // import the Vuex store

firebase.initializeApp(config)

export const auth = firebase.auth()
// export other Firebase bits like db, etc

const onAuthStateChangedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    store.commit(user !== null ? 'LOGIN' : 'LOGOUT', user)
    resolve(user)
  }, err => {
    reject(err)
  })
})

export const onAuthStateInit = () => onAuthStateChangedPromise
```

The `onAuthStateChanged` listener keeps the store in sync with the user's *auth* status yet the outer promise only resolves once (subsequent calls to `resolve()` are ignored). Due to this feature of promises, the `onAuthStateChangedPromise` can be used to detect when the Firebase authentication system has completed its initialisation phase.

I've then exposed that promise as a function named `onAuthStateInit`.

In my router, I use a `meta` flag named `public` to determine if a route is publicly accessible or not (most routes don't have it which means they need authentication).

My global navigation guard looks like this

```js
import { onAuthStateInit } from './firebase'

// define routes, new VueRouter, etc

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  await onAuthStateInit() // wait for auth system to initialise
  if (to.matched.every(route => route.meta.public) || store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next()
  } else {
    next({ name: 'sign-in' }) // redirect to sign-in page
  }
})
```

You can use `await onAuthStateInit()` anywhere where you would need to wait for that first-page-load auth initialisation to complete. You can call this as many times as is necessary and it will only ever wait one time. Once the auth initialisation is complete, this promise will resolve instantly.

My `sign-in` page uses the Firebase Auth UI with the following *callbacks* defined

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import 'firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css'

const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth)

export default {
  mounted () {
    // the ref is just a <div> in my template
    const container = this.$refs.firebaseuiAuthContainer
    ui.start(container, { 
      // signInOptions, etc
      callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: authResult => {
          this.$router.push({ name: 'home' }) // go to homepage or wherever
        },
        signInFailure: err => {
          // handle sign-in error
        }
      }
    })    
  }
}
```

You don't have to use the Auth UI. Any changes to the authenticated state of the current user will be caught by the `onAuthStateChange` listener so you can use the manual `auth.SignInWith*()` methods if you want.

Comment: Why does onAuthStateInit only run once? Doesn't it create a new promise each time?

Comment: @KelvinZhao no, you can see it returns the `onAuthStateChangedPromise` which is created only once. I only made it a function because `await onAuthStateInit()` looks better than `await onAuthStateChangedPromise`

Comment: Ah... So on when you `return new Promise`, it locks it upon first resolve, while if you `new Promise`, it runs a new promise each time? Is that how it works?

Comment: @KelvinZhao there is no `return new Promise` in my answer. `onAuthStateChangedPromise` is a `Promise` that is only created once. The `onAuthStateInit` function returns that same promise each time it's called

Comment: Sorry, one last question, what happens when the user signs out, then signs back in. The `onAuthStateInit` will return as true, but there is still a split second where the user is logging in, thus if I point them to the restricted page before that split second is up, it will bounce back to home.

Comment: @KelvinZhao you mean if the sign-in flow redirects back to your page? The `onAuthStateInit` doesn't resolve until `onAuthStateChange` has fired at least once. When it does, the user will be signed in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218493/discussion-between-kelvin-zhao-and-phil).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `signInWithRedirect` method with `AuthProvider` of your choice along with the `getRedirectResult` method . For example with Google:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
            if (result.additionalUserInfo && result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
                // User just created.
            }
            if (result.user) {
                // User just signed in.
            }
        });
        // User is signed in.
    }
    else {
        // User is signed out.
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    }
});
```

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#methods