# Vue Routes logout the apps when access the routes manually from search bar

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vue-cli

I have created an app using vue-cli for the first time and started using vue router along with it. I have created some routes which can be accessed based on auth state - Login, home etc.

This is what happening in my app -

1. If I try to access the routes before logging in, from the URL bar/search bar in the browser, I get redirected to login route which is great and works fine.
2. When I login in the app I can access nested routes by clicking buttons in the app in home route easily which is also fine.
3. But when I try to -

   a.  Refresh the page, I get loggout from the app

   b. Access nested route from the url, I get logged out from the app

Here is my **actions.js** for vuex store

```
const actions = {
  checkAdmin() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        router.push('/home');
      } else {
        router.push('/');
      }
    });
  },
  login(context) {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((res) => {
        context.dispatch('setAdmin', res.user);
        context.dispatch('setAuthState', true);
        router.push('/home');
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('err:', err);
      });
  },
  signout(context) {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      context.dispatch('setAdmin', null);
      router.push('/');
    }, function (error) {
      console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
    });
  },
  setAdmin(context, payload) {
    context.commit('setAdmin', payload);
  },
  setTheme(context, payload) {
    context.commit('setTheme', payload);
  },
  setVizType(context, payload) {
    context.commit('setVizType', payload);
  },
  fetchUsersList(context, payload) {
    context.commit('setUserList', payload.length > 0 ? payload : ['user 1', 'user 2', 'user 3', 'user 4', 'user 5']);
  },
  setSelectedUser(context, payload) {
    context.commit('setSelectedUser', payload);
    context.commit('setSessionList', [payload + ' session 1', payload + ' session 2', payload + ' session 3', payload + ' session 4']);
  },
  fetchSessionList(context, payload) {
    context.commit('setSessionList', payload);
  },
  setSelectedSession(context, payload) {
    context.commit('setSession', payload);
  }
};
```

And here is my router file

```
const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      console.log("beforeEnter", store.state.authenticated);
      if (store.state.authenticated) {
        console.log("Home");
        next();
      } else {
        next("/");
        console.log("Login");
      }
    },
    children: [{
      path: 'dashboard',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      component: Dashboard
    }, {
      path: 'settings',
      name: 'Settings',
      component: Settings
    }]
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: This is usually an issue with Firebase where you need to wait for the auth module to complete initialisation before querying it. I've seen this question asked and answered before. I'll post a link when I find it

Comment: Do either of these answer your question? [Attempting to make firebase.auth().currentUser a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047603/attempting-to-make-firebase-auth-currentuser-a-promise) or [Firebase Auth and Vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648240/firebase-auth-and-vue-router)

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem by modifying my Login.vue component. It seems when login component loads, it doesn't check if user is already signed in or not. To do that, I have dispatch  checkAdmin from a method defined in Login.vue when it gets mounted.

That way I can check if user is logged and update the admin state everytime user refreshed the page or go to the default url.

I hope this answer helps someone who is doing all firebase operation inside vuex store and encounter the same problem.

I have decided to move my firebase operation in vuex store just to make my app cleaner.