# Firebase logouton page refresh in vue app

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I am building a vue.js app using firebase for the backend. I've set up authentication and a route guard. I have also set the persistance of the session to firebase.persistance.LOCAL but, whenever I refresh the page, close the tab or browser and come back, I am being redirected to the login page.

This is my firebase config:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

var firebaseConfig = {
  ....
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const storage = firebase.storage();
```

This is how I log users in:

```
auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
                .then(function() {
                  auth
                    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(self.email, self.password)
                    .then(function() {
                      self.$router.push("/management");
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                      self.errors = error;
                      document.getElementById("signInLoader").style.display =
                        "none";
                    });
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                  self.errors = error;
                  document.getElementById("signInLoader").style.display =
                    "none";
                });
```

This is my route guard:

```
import { auth } from "@/firebase/firebase.js";

Vue.use(VueSpinners);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    next("/signin");
  } else if (requiresAuth && currentUser) {
    next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attempting to make firebase.auth().currentUser a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047603/attempting-to-make-firebase-auth-currentuser-a-promise)

Comment: Yep. I think this is what's happening

Comment: If you follow the link in my answer to the Firebase issue on Github, there are a bunch of other work-arounds mentioned there that you can also try. Short answer is you need to wait for the Firebase auth system to finish initialising (signaled by `onAuthStateChanged`) before you can even attempt to check `currentUser`

Answer (score -1):

I changed routeguard to watch for auth initialization and then check for currentUser.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
        if (!requiresAuth) {
            next()
        } else if (requiresAuth && user) {
            next()
        } else {
            next("/signin");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No, you don't want to be registering an auth-state-change listener every time you navigate. That's going to lead to all sorts of problems. Use an initialisation promise like in the post I linked above